# Semáforos en Linux

Tags: c, linux

Control semaforos Teóricamente. Simpre se queda en el `wait` del primer hijo y no ejecuta "codigo despues del wait". Quiero que el padre le devuelva el control con un `sem_signal`;

```
    for(i=0;i<NUM_HIJOS;i++)
        {

        switch(hijos[i].pid=fork())
         {
         case -1:
         printf("hubo un error en la creacion de los hijos.\n");
            return 3;
         case 0:
          printf("soy un hijo");
          **wait(&semaforo);**
         printf("codigo despues del wait");

        }
         sem_signal(&semaforo)
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes...

Wait se usa en el padre para esperar que los hijos terminen, no en los hijos.

`Wait(null)` espera que termine cualquier proceso hijo. Devuelve el pid del proceso que termino.

`Wait(&st)` guarda el valor de return del hijo en st.

Lo que estas haciendo mal es usar el wait en un hijo, cuando debería estar en el padre.